# creating new file with a name taken from the value of variables

Tags: c

My question is about creating txt or plt file in C, actually i want to create file with use of value of variables for file name, that may change step by step, for example: if x equals to 1, creating "Initial Field_1.plt" and for the next step maybe x equals to 0.001, creating "Initial Field_0.001.plt",
How should i change my code?
"

```
double Kn=0.001;    
char filename[80];
    sprintf(filename, "Initial Field_%f.plt", Kn);
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("Initial Field.plt", "w");"
    fprintf(fp, "variables = x, n, U, P, T, qx\n")

;
```

Comment: And what is the question? What have you tried doing and where is the problem?

Comment: New file can be created with fopen(...), snprintf(...)  can be used to create string with filename you want.

Comment: In line with fopen delete extra double quote and change first argument to file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf`

```
int x = 1;
char filename[80];
sprintf(filename, "Initial Field_%d.plt", x);
```

For other types of x see the documentation of sprintf.